# Can I precompile .ts files for Angular components / services / templates to .js?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've been using Angular for a couple years now and slightly embarrassed to ask this question - but also unable to find a comprehensive answer!

I was hoping that Angular CLI would be able to support and benefit from the [typescript `--incremental` build flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html) but unfortunately [it seems like it really won't](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13941#issuecomment-534052377).

So I'm looking for other ways to speed up my build (I am using Angular CLI), and I've already given up on bazel and closure since they seem to require a whole build team to set up.

I realize that a great deal of compilation time is spent for a lot of 'non typescript' things like bundler optimization and template compilation, but is there any benefit to be had from compiling normal `.ts` files in my project proactively into `.js` files.

I couldn't find much about this at all. Not even sure if it works and if it does work if it works for templates or just for .ts files that don't contain 'angular' constructs.

Comment: `So I'm looking for other ways to speed up my build...` ← Have you already done things like upgrade to the latest version of angular (10 at the time of writing this) and tried to do additional investigation as to why your build might be slow? Also are you focusing on the build speed during development or creating production builds?

Comment: @igor yes I’m using v10. Most during development is what I’m concerned about.

Comment: Does `ng build --watch` / `ng serve` not detect changes and refresh the running code fast  enough? What is your average wait time from change to refreshed code?